# Invert a scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator

Tags: python, scipy, linear-algebra

I have a linear function

```
def linear_function(x):
    return np.array([3*x[0], 4*x[2], -5*x[1]])
```

from which I construct a linear operator

```
L = LinearOperator((3,3),matvec=linear_function)
```

I want to invert this function.

One way to do this would be to construct the matrix corresponding to `L`, by passing in the unit vectors. But as outlined in [this question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/41975/recover-sparse-matrix-from-linear-operator), it is not recommended and is very slow (in my actual case, the dimensions of the matrix are of ~10000x10000).

Is there a quick and efficient way for inverting such large linear operators?

Comment: So is this what you are trying to avoid? 
 `np.linalg.inv(L@np.eye(3))`

Comment: If you found a CS discussion, with `scipy` code, what more do you expect from SO?  Why do you need the inverse, which will be a large matrix, sparse or dense?  All `inv` solve `A@X=I`

Comment: Is  your `matvec` always like this, with just one term per row/column (of the implied matrix)?

Comment: By the way, if only given `matvec`, `matmat` is implemented as `np.hstack([self.matvec(col.reshape(-1,1)) for col in X.T])`, i.e. iterative `matvec` on each column of the other array.

Comment: Does the matrix corresponding to your LinearOperator have any useful properties? For example, is it diagonaliziable? Is it positive definite? You could also try using [spsolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve.html) to find a vector `y` such that `Ay = x`. Not sure how fast that would be, though.

Comment: I want to invert the operator so that I can act it one another operator; it is not to compute the solution for a linear system. I think I will stick to the method @hpaulj mentioned for now

Comment: @hpaulj No, in my case the matvec is not sparse in the manner you've mentioned, but sparse in the sense that it is in block form (with most of the off diagonal blocks being zero). I tried to invert it using sparse methods by scipy.sparse.linalg.inv(sparse.csc_matrix(L@np.eye(N))), but it still takes too much time (inverse of a sparse block matrix is reasonably sparse I believe?)

Comment: @NickODell I am using sparse inverse (refer to the above comment), which implements an spsolve under the hood already (https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.12.0/scipy/sparse/linalg/_matfuncs.py#L31-L77)

Comment: @haricash Both are doing spsolve, yes. However, note that inv is doing an spsolve where b is a matrix, which is slower than doing an spsolve where b is a vector. (I assume - I haven't tested this idea.)